# Slavoj Žižek on Silicon Valley culture

Tags: reference-request, zizek

I'm looking for a certain remark made about Silicon Valley technologists as "fascists". Or a related remark.

I don't remember if it was part of an article or something said in an interview.

Comment: This isn't exactly an uncommon opinion -- http://thebaffler.com/blog/mouthbreathing-machiavellis